# calculating the min/max and add to new column

Tags: python, pandas

a Python pandas question that should be really simple but I just cannot find the answer

Imagine this dataframe. I want to add a new column called "max" filled with the high up until that moment(date)... so not calculated on the complete dataframe, not rolling.. but just until then.

```
                      open     high      low    close
date
2022-06-27 07:58:00  31502.5  31504.0  31500.0  31503.0
2022-06-27 07:58:10  31503.0  31503.5  31501.0  31502.0
2022-06-27 07:58:20  31502.0  31502.0  31500.5  31502.0
```

Comment: What is the expected output of this example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the index column is sorted you can use `cummax` function (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4], "B": [1, 8, 4, 2]}).set_index("A")
df["cummax"] = df["B"].cummax()
df
```

Output -

```
   B  cummax
A
1  1       1
2  8       8
3  4       8
4  2       8
```

Comment: df['max'] = df.high.expanding(min_periods=1).max() also works.